# Feasibility of a MSSQL Read Only Replicas as ephermal containers?

Tags: sql-server

Kubernetes tends to get more complex to work with when persistent state becomes a concern. Therefore it can be attractive to keep applications in a cluster as stateless as possible.

In the aim of optimizing sql read performance across multiple regions in an environment with Kubernetes clusters [in multiple regions], is it possible to run MSSQL server as a container (stateless read-only replica) in each cluster with a primary [located in a single region] that would handle writes while replicating changes out to the secondaries?

The primary aspect I'm trying to hit on is the feasibility of running stateless MS SQL containers that can easily reintegrate with the primary if they are arbitrarily killed or if new copies are brought up.

Comment: Without persistent storage the newly [re]started containers wouldn't have any data to them, would they.

Comment: I am presuming a mechanism of some kind propagates state from the primary. Otherwise there would be no data on a secondary to persist.  I'm not sure what mechanisms exist there (lazy as data is needed vs greedy and up front with incremental updates) and what kind of rates of transfer are acceptable - and that gets into my question. It seems reasonable to me though, that a few hundred MB database would be feasible to transfer every now and then for a new instance. I'm just not sure what current technology enables "out of the box."

Comment: May be you could read how read-only replicas are usually set up.

Comment: I have done some reading on that, but I was hoping a community like this could offer some perspective and insights.  I don't know  nuances of the methods that might fit here and if configurations like this are less commonly done. A google search is not going to provide this. A community like this I was hoping could. If I was setting up my own long lived servers with log shipping, reading an article would be the best source of information. The ideas I'm asking about I felt were better suited to be asked to those with experience.

Comment: I feel like many of the SE communities have gotten much more cold with answering questions over the recent years. It seems like 10 years ago it was much more about producing valuable insights and answers  Maybe it's a change in experience or expectations for my part or a combination.  If anyone knows of a community more suited for questions like this, I'd appreciate a call out.

Comment: I'm a little confused on your goals to be honest. The only thing I know about Kubernetes is how to spell it . But particularly I'm not sure if you're saying you want your secondaries to change minimally or you do want them to stay consistent with the primary, and if so, how frequently? My instincts tell me what you want to achieve is not best handled with cluster synchronization technologies (such as Availability Groups) but there's probably a technology and methodology to achieve what you want, so if you could please clarify your goals that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

> Kubernetes tends to get more complex to work with when persistent state becomes a concern.

Correct, Kubernetes is essentially useless for stateful items. People keep trying to use it that way... with horrible outcomes.

> [...] is it possible to run MSSQL server as a container (stateless read-only replica) in each cluster with a primary [located in a single region] that would handle writes while replicating changes out to the secondaries?

Yes, but I'd argue that it would be "doing it wrong". I'm just a rando on the intenet, so there's that to take into account. If something needs to be truly expansive to handle scale out and (for example, in this case) holds constantly changing data that needs to be saved (can't be loaded from another source when needed), then it should be architected as such.

> The primary aspect I'm trying to hit on is the feasibility of running stateless MS SQL containers that can easily reintegrate with the primary if they are arbitrarily killed or if new copies are brought up.

You can do this with a special setup of an Availability Group (feature) utilizing the [read-scale configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/read-scale-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15) along with the [automatic seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/automatic-seeding-secondary-replicas?view=sql-server-ver15) option. I wish you good luck.